# How can VBA alerts generated from Word macros be disabled?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I'm working on an application that processes Word documents using interop.

Here's how I set up the `Application`:

```
Application app = new Application()
{
    DisplayAlerts = wdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
};

app.Application.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
```

I'm trying to disable all alerts and prevent macros from executing. However, after adding the last line that disables macros, I get the following alert from VBA:

[image]

Do I need to disable VBA alerts as well? If so, how can I do that? This alert stops execution of the application until I deal with it.

Comment: You are trying to use the interop library while preventing macros? I may be mistaken but I'd be willing to throw 5 on the assumption that the interop is going to cause issues with security because it is using the same underlying objects. So, while you may want to prevent macros, you can still call `Application.Run("Macroname")` or whatever the syntax is just by using the interop alone. The interop allows you to run macros but you don't want macros is what I'm getting at. But I could be wrong.

Comment: `wdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone` is part of VBA library. I don't think you can avoid that one showing an alert if you disable all macros is what I'm getting at... I think.